# Upload APK to Github with TravisCI

Tags: android, bash, github, apk

There is a bash script to upload `APK` file to `GitHub` repository after successful `TravisCI` build.

```
  mkdir $HOME/buildApk/
  mkdir $HOME/android/

  cp -R app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk $HOME/android/
  cd $HOME
  git config --global user.email "myemail@myemail.com"
  git config --global user.name "Akos Kovacs" 

  git clone --quiet --branch=master  https://plaidshirtakos:$GITHUB_API_KEY@github.com/plaidshirtakos/Trivia-test  master > /dev/null
  cd master cp -Rf $HOME/android/* .

  git add -f .
  git remote rm origin
  git remote add origin https://plaidshirtakos:$GITHUB_API_KEY@github.com/plaidshirtakos/Trivia-test.git
  git add -f .
  git commit -m "Travis build $TRAVIS_BUILD_NUMBER pushed"
  git push -fq origin master > /dev/null
  echo "Done"
```

I see following lines in log.

> On branch master nothing to commit, working tree clean Done

Comment: Did you register to exclude apk in gitignore?

Comment: @kimkevin : I didn't added it to be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

You may miss git add command.

```
git add -A
```

`-f` is "Allow adding otherwise ignored files."

`-A` is "If no <pathspec> is given when -A option is used, all files in the entire working tree are updated"

Changed your sample code:

```
mkdir $HOME/buildApk/
mkdir $HOME/android/

cp -R app/build/outputs/apk/*.apk $HOME/android/
cd $HOME
git config --global user.email "myemail@myemail.com"
git config --global user.name "Akos Kovacs" 

git clone --depth=10 --branch=master  https://plaidshirtakos:$GITHUB_API_KEY@github.com/plaidshirtakos/Trivia-test  master > /dev/null
cd master
cp -Rf $HOME/android/* .

git add -A
git commit -m "Travis build $TRAVIS_BUILD_NUMBER pushed"
git push -fq origin master > /dev/null
echo "Done"
```

See also a sample that use ssh+git:

https://github.com/indication/OpenRedmine/blob/development/external/report.sh

Comment: I got following message during build: "Skipping a deployment with the releases provider because this branch is not permitted"

Comment: Is your master branch protected to push? Which command got the message?

Comment: I see this on Travis, without command. I didn't set this branch protected.